# Simple System.out printing

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point, public, system.out

Ok guys I have this problem how do I code this
but without empty line between

x

xy

xxy

xxyy

xxxyy

xxxyyy

Here is my code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("x");
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){

        for(int j = 0;j<i;j++){
            System.out.print("x");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `y` come from? Exactly what empty lines do you want to eliminate?

Comment: If you mean the newlines, its the `println()` call that is causing that.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is as follows:

1x, 0y

1x, 1y

2x, 1y

2x, 2y...

So your loop should look something like this:

```
int xCount = 0;
int yCount = 0;
int total = 3;
do {
    if (xCount == yCount) xCount++;
    else yCount++;
    for (int x = 0; x < xCount; x++) System.out.print("x");
    for (int y = 0; y < yCount; y++) System.out.print("y");
    System.out.println();
 } while (yCount < total);
```